# php variable not returning what is expected

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, ternary-operator

I have an unordered list that's being generated from a database. Depending on the value of one of the returned fields, the li tag's class should be set to different values. Unfortunately they're all returning "inactive". I know this must be something simple, but I've been staring at it for hours and am just not seeing it.

Here's the code:

```
<ul class="tabs">
   <? foreach ($tracks AS $track) {
    $active = (strtolower($track->shortname === 'dpp')) ? ' class="active"' : 'class="inactive"';
    echo "<p>".strtolower($track->shortname). " is ".$active."</p>"; ?>
    <li <?= $active; ?>><a href="#<?= strtolower($track->shortname); ?>"><?= $track->name; ?></a></li>
   <? } ?>
</ul>
```

Here's what is actually getting printed:

```
<ul class="tabs"> 
    <p>dpp is class="inactive"</p>  <li class="inactive"><a href="#dpp">Digital Path to Purchase</a></li> 
    <p>cre is class="inactive"</p>  <li class="inactive"><a href="#cre">Fueling Creativity</a></li> 
</ul>
```

It's obvious that the first one is returning $track-shortname of dpp, so why is the $active variable not getting set to "class=active"?

Comment: Watch your brackets: `strtolower($track->shortname === 'dpp')` => `strtolower($track->shortname) === 'dpp'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made an error in the expression where you check the shortname:

```
$active = (strtolower($track->shortname === 'dpp')) ? ' class="active"' : 'class="inactive"';
                     ^                           ^
```

You most certainly only want to put it around `$track->shortname`:

```
$active = (strtolower($track->shortname) === 'dpp') ? ' class="active"' : 'class="inactive"';
                     ^                 ^
```

Otherwise you tried to lowercase a boolean value which is either true or false but in your case it looks to always be false, hence the inactive CSS class.

BTW, you can spare another pair:

```
$active = strtolower($track->shortname) === 'dpp' ? ' class="active"' : 'class="inactive"';
         ^                                       ^
```

Comment: Thank you; I did some copy/paste work and misplaced the closing parentheses. I knew it would be something like that!\

Answer (score 1):

The code `(strtolower($track->shortname === 'dpp'))` looks wrong.  Your putting the `strtolower` around the comparison, and you probably just want it around the `$track->shortname`.

Answer (score 1):

One of your close parentheses is in the wrong place.

Change:

```
$active = (strtolower($track->shortname === 'dpp')) ? ' class="active"' : 'class="inactive"';
```

To:

```
$active = (strtolower($track->shortname) === 'dpp') ? ' class="active"' : 'class="inactive"';
```

With the parenthesis in the wrong place, `$track->shortname` is compared to `dpp` before any lower-case conversion. Then the result of that comparison (boolean) is passed to `strtolower`. That results in `strtolower` simply returning a string representation of that which results in the ternary comparison evaluating to false.

Comment: Thanks. Same answer as hakre below; just saw that one a minute sooner.